# Ошибка при разборе JSON-ответа

Tags: android, json

Есть необходимость изменить содержание кода php при котором меняется JSON-ответ. Вроде и разница всего-то в КАВЫЧКАХ, а выводит ошибку.
Код PHP при котором получается выводить успешно:

```
<?php // серверная часть вывода json

$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if($login == "user" & $pass == "pass") {
?>      {
"data":[

{
"name":"Lobs",
"reit":"110",
"balance":"99"
}
]
}<?php }
?>
```

Код PHP при котором появляется ошибка -

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"balance":99,"reit":110,"name":"Lobs"} at data of type
>   org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray:

```
<?php // серверная часть вывода json

$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if($login == "user" & $pass == "pass") {
?>      {
"data":[

{
"name":"Lobs",
"reit":110,
"balance":99
}
]
}<?php }
?>
```

Как пробую выводить:

```
public void JSONURL(String result) {
    textView20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    textView34 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView34);
    textView60 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView60);
    try {
        //создали читателя json объектов и отдали ему строку - result
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        //дальше находим вход в наш json им является ключевое слово data
        JSONArray urls = json.getJSONArray("data");
        //проходим циклом по всем нашим параметрам
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm;
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр balance
            hm.put(NAME, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString());
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр reit
            hm.put(REIT, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("reit").toString());
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр balance
            hm.put(BALANCE, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("balance").toString());
            myBooks.add(hm);


            //выводим
            textView20.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("name"));
            textView34.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("reit"));
            textView60.setText((CharSequence) hm.get("balance"));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Знаю что есть лишний код, что не грамотно написано...
Что нужно поменять? Уже по всякому пробовал...((( Имейте ввиду что я начинающий программист ;). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: мне кажется, кроме кавычек вы где-то потеряли еще и квадратные скобки []. выведите в лог `result` перед тем, как использовать его

Comment: Абсолютно верно! Проверил result а там действительно нет квадратных скобок: {"data":{"name":"Lobs","reit":110,"balance":99}}. Что посоветуете сделать? Обязательно ли переделывать ПХП?

Comment: Как хоитите, если там должен быть массив, а не объект, то обязательно. Если там будет только один объект, просто измените код, чтобы он ожидал не массив, а объект.

Comment: Да, да, да!! Спасибо!! :)))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кроме кавычек вы где-то потеряли еще и квадратные скобки `[]`. В итоге, у вас на месте `JSONArray` получается `JSONObject`. выведите в лог `result` перед тем, как использовать его